# undefined method `allow' for #<RSpec:: Rspec 3.6.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to Rails and specially to writing tests. I keep getting the error `undefined method allow` and `undefined method allow_any_instance_of'` when I run the test. 
I've checked Rspec > 3 should accept the allow syntax, what is the issue in my code?

```
describe "GET #show" do

    let(:sample_json_list) {
      "{\"files\":[{\"title\":\"discourse-2017-08-24-085545-v20170803123704.sql.gz\",\"id\":\"0B7WjYjWZJv_4MENlYUM2SjkyU1E\",\"size\":\"14070939\",\"created_at\":\"2017-08-24T06:56:21.698+00:00\"}]}"
    }

    before {
      allow_any_instance_of(DiscourseDownloadFromDrive::DriveDownloader).to receive(:json_list).and_return(sample_json_list)
    }

    it "renders the json" do
      get :show
      response.body.should == sample_json_list
    end

  end
```

Comment: Can you run your spec with `-b` option and show more log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, first of all configure `expect` syntax. Would be look like:

```
# spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :expect
  end
end
```

And now `allow_any_instance_of` will work like charm.
But, then syntax would be look like:

```
it "renders the json" do
  get :show
  expect(response.body).to eq(sample_json_list)
end
```

Cheers!

Comment: ah! I see, so if the project has `RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fail_fast = ENV['RSPEC_FAIL_FAST'] == "1"
  config.include Helpers
  config.include MessageBus
  config.include RSpecHtmlMatchers
  config.include IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
  config.mock_framework = :mocha
  config.order = 'random'
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!`

It means is using Mocha syntax instead the rspec expect?

Comment: I afraid so. By default `mock_framework` is `:rspec`. So maybe just removing `config.mock_framework = :mocha` will work too. :)